# Bug: Ugly white space on top of my website. Can't figure out, why

Tags: html, css

I have a problem on my [blog](http://inge.timrodenbroeker.de).

In firefox theres an ugly space on top of the site, which is not visible in chrome and i don't get rid of it. Firebug didn't help anyway.

It's weird: When i change the margin-bottom of my `<div class="ontop">`, then the space appears. if i set it to 0, its gone!

Could you please help me? Thanx!

Comment: your link continuously loading not even figure out what the issue.

Comment: Please provide som code instead of just linking to your site.
You can either add your code directly here or add it to [JSFIddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: @NatalieHedström The problem is quite unusual and will probably be really hard to reproduce in a minimal code example.

Comment: @connexo That might or might not be the case, but Stack Overflow is a code base/library, so to help people in the future that might experience the same issues as you do it would be still be helpfull to provide some code.
Also if you can't reproduce it in JSFiddle then that's one step closer to solving the issue. :)

Comment: @NatalieHedström, Why do you recommend 'jsfiddle' instead of code snippet feature provided by stackoverflow?

Comment: Just put a `float:left` for ontop.

Comment: @technorevolutionary When I wrote that he/she could add it here directly I meant through stack overflow, either by using the code snippet feature or by just adding the code. Sorry, that might have been unclear :)

Comment: @OP: Don't forget to mark the answer that beste explained/solved your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some issue of  'margin-bottom: 300px`in .ontop` class in firefox. It is something weird.

Set `height: 100%;` will do the trick. and remove top margin.

I think this is [bug in firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=717880).

Answer (score 0):

Even though I don't have the time right now to figure out *why* this problem occurs, here's a **quick fix**:

Change the

```
margin-bottom: 300px;
```

to

```
padding-bottom: 300px;
```

## Edit:

Somehow this problem seems to result from a non-explicitly set height for `.ontop`. If you set

```
height: 82px; /* Height of your logo */
```

the problem also disappears and you can continue using `margin-bottom`.

Answer (score 0):

give class .wrapper{display:inline-block}.
it will solve the issue.class .ontop to {float:left}